# How do I filter an array of a class in swift that returns an array of a subclass of the original class?

Tags: swift, filter, casting, mapping

How do I filter an array of objects of a certain class and return the results to an array of of a subclass of the original class? Specifically to filter and array of CKRecord and return the results to an array of [CKShare], like thus:

```
let records = [CKRecord]()

let shares: [CKShare] = records.filter({ $0 is CKShare })
```

The code above generates a code-time error message "Cannot assign value of type '[CKRecord]' to type '[CKShare]'".

I wonder if I could use a map method to work with the filter method to do what I want to do, or a version of the map method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `compactMap` for this.

```
let shares = records.compactMap({ $0 as? CKShare })
```

If you want to filter also your records then you can write like this.

```
//Replace $0.isEnable with your condition, if that is true then cast it for sub class CKShare else return nil
let shares = records.compactMap({ $0.isEnable ? $0 as? CKShare : nil })
```

Comment: Ok. I got as good as ```let shares: [CKShare] = records.filter({ $0 is CKShare }).map({ $0 as! CKShare })```

Comment: But you are looping twice, which is unnecessary, `compactMap` is `filter + map`

Comment: Yeah. I tried to click on the checkmark to accept your answer. It wouldn't let me do it until a minute. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome mate :), yes I know on timer for acceptance, what I was saying is instead of looping twice better to use `compactMap`.